# Factorise $x^{111}+9x^{74}+27x^{37}+27$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I am having trouble with the following.

> Factorise $x^{111}+9x^{74}+27x^{37}+27$ in irreducible factors in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

I did not find it to be an Eisentein polynomial and trying to find zeros by hand is a lot of work, so is a linear substitution of $x$ by $cx+b$. Also, reducing the polynomial modulo a prime number (for example 3) did not help.

Comment: Compute $2\times 37$ and $3\times 37$ and see if that lights the bulb.

Comment: As suggested by B. Goddard, with wild looking polynomials it is often useful to look for a pattern in the exponents on the variable. The hint by cansomeonehelpmeout puts the icing on the cake

Comment: $\left(x^{37}+3\right)^3$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**:

> Make the substitution $u=x^{37}$

---

*For completion. After the hint, you can write your expression like* $$\color{green}{1}\cdot 3^0\cdot u^3+\color{green}{3}\cdot 3^1\cdot u^2+\color{green}{3}\cdot 3^2\cdot u+\color{green}{1}\cdot 3^3\\(u+3)^3=(x^{37}+3)^3$$